# No carga el React Suspense

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, lazy-loading

Estoy intentando usar el componente  que viene con react, lo estoy usando de forma que se llama una función **Homee** con los componentes que quiero cargar, pero nunca se muestra el componente de cargando del **fallback** , entre las cosas que probe por si tenia algo mal:

- Usando el "Inspeccionar elemento -> Network" coloque la carga a "Slow 3G" para ver si llegaba a cargar pero no.

Aquí muestro como importo el Suspense y los componentes:

```
import React, {Fragment, Suspense} from 'react'   

 return (
   <Suspense delayMs={1} fallback={<Wait/>}>
     <Homee/>
   </Suspense>
 )

function Homee (){
   return(
   <Fragment>
     <Headbar/>
     <Land/>
     <Banner03/>
     <Lore/>
     <Banner01/>
     <BuyCS/>
     <Buy/> 
     <hr className="marX marB lineaHr"/>
     <Roadmap/>
     <Banner02/>
     <Team/>
     <Foot/>
   </Fragment>);
 }
```

Comment: Esta es la forma en que use el lazy pero lo descarte porque tampoco me funciono:

const Landd = React.lazy(()=>import('./Land'));                <Suspense fallback={<h1>CARGANDO...</h1>}><Landd/></Suspense>

Comment: Se deben usar en conjunto de [acuerdo a la Doc](https://yeisondaza.com/todo-lo-que-debes-saber-sobre-react-suspense), la propiedad `delayMs` parece   ser legacy, además, de acuerdo a [esta publicación](https://yeisondaza.com/todo-lo-que-debes-saber-sobre-react-suspense), no se vera el mensaje de fullfill muy seguido, debido a que estas en carga local.

Comment: Realice los cambios para usar lazy y suspense, pero aun no funciona.

Comment: Bien, entonces dices que no carga `Land`, ¿Hay mensajes en la consola? Si pudieras mostrar como estas importando `Land`

Comment: Hice algunos cambios en el codigo, de tal forma que sin usar el **lazy** el suspense carga la funcion **Homee** y los compenentes de Homee si cargan, pero no se muestra en ningun momento el <Wait/>